# Delete the attributes from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects as metioned below

```
Flag =[{type: "folder", name: "Real Estate", order: "1", delete: "false", canModify: "true"}
 {type: "folder", name: "Legal", order: "2", delete: "false", canModify: "false"}
 {type: "folder", name: "Construction", order: "3", delete: "false", canModify: "true"}
 {type: "folder", name: "Design", order: "4", delete: "false", canModify: "true"}];
```

I want to remove **name,order** from the array my output should look like

```
Flag =[{type: "folder",  delete: "false", canModify: "true"}
 {type: "folder",   delete: "false", canModify: "false"}
 {type: "folder",  delete: "false", canModify: "true"}
 {type: "folder",  delete: "false", canModify: "true"}];
```

Which is the better way to do it, *array.splice()* or *array.pop()*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you could use `splice` and `pop` for this, I'd use the rest operator to remove the properties:

```js
const Flag = [{
  type: "folder",
  name: "Real Estate",
  order: "1",
  delete: "false",
  canModify: "true"
}, {
  type: "folder",
  name: "Legal",
  order: "2",
  delete: "false",
  canModify: "false"
}, {
  type: "folder",
  name: "Construction",
  order: "3",
  delete: "false",
  canModify: "true"
}, {
  type: "folder",
  name: "Design",
  order: "4",
  delete: "false",
  canModify: "true"
}, ];

const result = Flag.map(x => {
  const {
    name,
    order,
    ...rest,
  } = x;

  return rest;
});

console.dir(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to remove the property into the object with [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator

```js
Flag =[{type: "folder", name: "Real Estate", order: "1", delete: "false", canModify: "true"},
 {type: "folder", name: "Legal", order: "2", delete: "false", canModify: "false"},
 {type: "folder", name: "Construction", order: "3", delete: "false", canModify: "true"},
 {type: "folder", name: "Design", order: "4", delete: "false", canModify: "true"}];
 
 Flag.forEach( obj => { 
   delete obj.name; 
   delete obj.order; 
 });
 
 console.log(Flag)
```

`array.splice()` or `array.pop()` will remove the object into your array and not the properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete` keyword to delete properties of object

```js
let Flag =[{type: "folder", name: "Real Estate", order: "1", delete: "false", canModify: "true"},
 {type: "folder", name: "Legal", order: "2", delete: "false", canModify: "false"},
 {type: "folder", name: "Construction", order: "3", delete: "false", canModify: "true"},
 {type: "folder", name: "Design", order: "4", delete: "false", canModify: "true"}];
 
Flag.forEach(obj => {
  delete obj.name;
  delete obj.order;
})
console.log(Flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use delete

```js
Flag = [{
    type: "folder",
    name: "Real Estate",
    order: "1",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "true"
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "Legal",
    order: "2",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "false"
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "Construction",
    order: "3",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "true"
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "Design",
    order: "4",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "true"
  }
];

function del() {
  for (i = 0; i < Flag.length; i++) {
    if (Flag[i].name) delete Flag[i].name;
    if (Flag[i].order) delete Flag[i].order;
  }
  return Flag;
}
console.log(del());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**

```js
Flag = [{
    type: "folder",
    name: "Real Estate",
    order: "1",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "true"
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "Legal",
    order: "2",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "false"
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "Construction",
    order: "3",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "true"
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "Design",
    order: "4",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "true"
  }
];
var removeKeys = ['name', 'order'];
myArray = Flag.filter(function(obj) {
  removeKeys.forEach(e => delete obj[e]);
  return obj;
});
console.log(myArray);
```

**Approach 2**

```js
Flag = [{
    type: "folder",
    name: "Real Estate",
    order: "1",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "true"
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "Legal",
    order: "2",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "false"
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "Construction",
    order: "3",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "true"
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    name: "Design",
    order: "4",
    delete: "false",
    canModify: "true"
  }
];
Flag = Flag.filter(function(obj) {
  delete obj.name;
  delete obj.order
  return obj;
});
console.log(Flag);
```